# Отрисовка страницы при загрузке, оптимизация

Tags: jquery, производительность

При загрузке страницы и записи в timeline на Chrome Dev Tool происходит сначала отдача html потом отрабатывают скрипты.

Все было бы нормально, но при прогрузке скриптов пропадает весь контент, становится невидимым потом заново отстраивается, и это визуально заметно.

При этом отрабатывает **jQuery**.

Как избавится от видимого мигания?

Comment: Страница не должна мигать. Нужно найти причину. Отключайте (коментируйте) куски js и узнаете какой код вызывает данное поведение. И задавайте вопрос по нему.